# DevForce ServerConsole - There is no end point listening

Tags: wcf, devforce

I have a basic DevForce Windows Store application using the free Windows Store license.

When running as a Web project, I was able to successfully execute queries successfully.

However, when hosted using ServerConsole.exe, I get the following exception:

> There is no endpoint listening on
>   `http://localhost:63191/EntityService.svc/winrt` that could accept calls
>   from this application. If running in Visual Studio, make sure
>   CopyLocal=true is set for all IdeaBlade assembly references in the web
>   project to ensure that these assemblies are copied to the bin folder.
>   Also check that the global.asax contains code to register the DevForce
>   VirtualPathProvider, or that the EntityService.svc and
>   EntityServer.svc files are present.
>   To check if the service is running, open your internet browser and
>   navigate to `http://localhost:63191/EntityService.svc`. If the service
>   page shows errors, these should help diagnose the problem with the
>   service. If the service is running, then also make sure that the
>   endpoint bindings match between client and server, and that the
>   server's ClientApplicationType is either 'All' or correct for this
>   client.  Check the server's debug log file for more information.

There are three projects in the solution, App1 (Windows Store), DomainModel (NET4.5) and App1.Web (Web Application). The ServiceConsole.exe was copied into the DomainModel's output directory.

The ServerConsole correctly reports:

```
Trying programmatic configuration of EntityService using
ideablade.configuration  section EntityService listening on
http://localhost:63191/EntityService/winrt EntityService listening on
http://localhost:63191/EntityService/wp Press <Enter> to exit server.
```

Navigating to

```
`http://localhost:63191/EntityService.svc` shows `404 Not Found`.

`http://localhost:63191/EntityService` shows the standard Web Service info page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an "infelicity" in DevForce.  For mobile clients it defaults to assuming that the EntityService will be hosted by IIS and automatically appends the .svc extension required by WCF.

To work around this behavior you can add a custom implementation of the DevForce ServiceProxyEvents class to strip out the extension and replace the URI.

```
class ClientProxy : IdeaBlade.EntityModel.ServiceProxyEvents
{

    public override void OnEndpointCreated(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        var olduri = endpoint.Address.Uri;
        var newuri = new Uri(olduri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(".svc", string.Empty));
        endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(newuri);
        base.OnEndpointCreated(endpoint);
    }
}
```

Place the class in a client-side assembly which will be "probed" by DevForce.

Comment: Hosted on is IIS a perfectly valid assumption.